# Specializations for different types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, specialization

Can someone tell me how to remove the repeated specializations below?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

struct Thing {
    int a, b;
    void load (std::istream& is) {is >> std::skipws >> a >> b;}
};

struct Object {
    int a, b, c;
    void load (std::istream& is) {is >> std::skipws >> a >> b >> c;}
};

template <typename...> struct PassArgs;

// General case.
template <typename First, typename... Rest>
struct PassArgs<First, Rest...> : PassArgs<Rest...> {
    void operator()(std::istream& is, First& first, Rest&... rest) const {
        is >> first;
        PassArgs<Rest...>::operator()(is, rest...);
    }
};

// Specialization for std::string needed.
template <typename... Rest>
struct PassArgs<std::string, Rest...> : PassArgs<Rest...> {
    void operator()(std::istream& is, std::string& first, Rest&... rest) const {
        while (std::getline (is, first) && first.empty());
        PassArgs<Rest...>::operator()(is, rest...);
    }
};

// Specialization for class Thing.
template <typename... Rest>
struct PassArgs<Thing, Rest...> : PassArgs<Rest...> {
    void operator()(std::istream& is, Thing& first, Rest&... rest) const {
        first.load(is);
        PassArgs<Rest...>::operator()(is, rest...);
    }
};

// Specialization for class Object, but is the exact same as that for Thing.
template <typename... Rest>
struct PassArgs<Object, Rest...> : PassArgs<Rest...> {
    void operator()(std::istream& is, Object& first, Rest&... rest) const {
        first.load(is);
        PassArgs<Rest...>::operator()(is, rest...);
    }
};


template <>
struct PassArgs<> {
    void operator()(std::istream&) const {}  // End of recursion.
};


int main() {}
```

Everything works correctly, but is there a way to avoid specializations for all classes that have the `load(std::istream&)` function (and there are many in my program).  Currently, I have specializations for `Thing`, `Object`, and many other classes which all have the same lines in their specializations.

Incidentally, this is how the client uses `PassArgs`:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
T* create (std::istream& is, Args&... args) {
    PassArgs<Args...>()(is, args...);
    T* t = new T(args...);
    // Do whatever with t;
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a trait to detect the `load` member:

```
template<typename T> using void_t = void;

template<typename T, typename = void_t<>>
  struct has_load
  : std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
  struct has_load<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T&>().load(std::declval<std::istream&>()))>>
  : std::true_type
  { };
```

Hoist the actual loading for a single type into a separate class template, specialized for types with a `load` member (using the trait):

```
template<typename T, bool use_load = has_load<T>::value>
  struct PassArg
  {
    static void pass(std::istream& is, T& t) { is >> t; }
  };

template<typename T>
  struct PassArg<T, true>
  {
    static void pass(std::istream& is, T& t) { t.load(is); }
  };
```

Then use that in your main template:

```
// General case.
template <typename First, typename... Rest>
  struct PassArgs : PassArgs<Rest...> {
    void operator()(std::istream& is, First& first, Rest&... rest) const
    {
        PassArg<First>::pass(is, first);
        PassArgs<Rest...>::operator()(is, rest...);
    }
};
```

The `string` case can be done by specializing `PassArg` too.

```
template<>
  struct PassArg<std::string, false>
  {
    static void pass(std::istream& is, std::string& s)
    { getline(is, s); }
  };
```

N.B. I made the new class have a static function called `pass` not `operator()`, because if you find yourself writing this:

```
PassArgs<Args...>()(is, args...);
```

or worse, calling `operator()` by name like this:

```
PassArgs<Rest...>::operator()(is, rest...);
```

Then you probably don't want a functor. `PassArgs` is stateless, so there's no point creating an instance of it, and if you have to name `operator()` explicitly then you're doing it wrong. Give the function a proper name and call that, and make it static:

```
PassArgs<Rest...>::sensible_name(is, rest...);
```

Comment: If you use a loading function instead of a loading type, you can get ADL customization as a bonus.

Comment: @Yakk, yes, although that might not always be desirable

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the `void_t` class here.  I tried to test fully your implementation:   http://ideone.com/pxYwUF   Replace my original `ForwardArgs<Args...>()(is, args...);` with `PassArgs<Args...>()(is, args...);` in the `T* create (std::istream& is, Args&... args)` function in my test program, and it doesn't compile.

Comment: @prestokeys `template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;}; template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;` is a variation on `void_t` that works on more compilers.  There was an ambiguity in the standard that has since been resolved that makes `template<class T>using void_t=void;` not work in some older compilers.

Comment: A small nitpick: implementing `PassArg` this way makes it tricky to partially specialize. I'd rename the current version to, say, `PassArgImpl` and add a `template<class T> struct PassArg;` that simply calls `PassArgImpl<T>` by default.

Comment: @T.C. yes, that's an improvement, I was just being lazy doing it this way (and thanks for fixing the copy&paste error in the answer)

Answer (score 6):

There are roughly one bazillion ways to do this. Here's one of them.

First, a trait to detect whether there is a member `load()` to be called. Here's one way to write it:

```
namespace details {    
    template<class T>
    auto has_load_impl(int) 
         -> decltype((void)std::declval<T&>().load(std::declval<std::istream&>()),
                     std::true_type());

    template<class T>
    std::false_type has_load_impl(...);

    template<class T>
    using has_load = decltype(has_load_impl<T>(0));
}
```

There are plenty of other ways to write this trait. Jonathan Wakely's answer uses Walter Brown's `void_t`, for instance. Or you may use [`std::experimental::is_detected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

Next, write a function that loads a single argument, dispatching based on the result of `has_load`. Here's one way to do it:

```
namespace details {
    template<class T>
    void do_load(std::istream& is, T& t, std::true_type /*has_load*/){
        t.load(is);
    }

    template<class T>
    void do_load(std::istream& is, T& t, std::false_type /*has_load*/){
        is >> t;
    }
}

template<class T>
void load(std::istream& is, T& t){
    details::do_load(is, t, details::has_load<T>());
}
```

It's also possible to dispense with the standalone trait, and SFINAE directly in the `do_load` functions, if you don't need the trait elsewhere:

```
namespace details {
    template<class T>
    auto do_load(std::istream& is, T& t, int) -> decltype((void)t.load(is)){
        t.load(is);
    }

    template<class T>
    void do_load(std::istream& is, T& t, ...){
        is >> t;
    }
}

template<class T>
void load(std::istream& is, T& t){
    details::do_load(is, t, 0);
}
```

Add overloads as needed for types requiring special treatment.

```
void load(std::istream& is, std::string& s){
    while (std::getline (is, s) && s.empty());
}
```

Finally, `PassArgs` itself can be simplified to a two-line function, using the familiar trick of pack expansion inside a *braced-init-list*:

```
template<class... Args>
void PassArgs(std::istream& is, Args&... args){
    using expander = int[];
    (void)expander{0, (load(is, args), void(), 0)... };
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cf306a7ac25fc47).

In the above, the user may customize `load` using ADL. Alternatively, you might make `load` a member function of a class template `loader<T>` instead, and users can specialize `loader` as desired to customize the load:

```
template<class T>
struct loader {
    static void load(std::istream& is, T& t) {
        details::do_load(is, t, details::has_load<T>());
    }
};

template<> struct loader<std::string>{
    static void load(std::istream& is, std::string& s){
        while (std::getline (is, s) && s.empty());
    }
};

template<class... Args>
void PassArgs(std::istream& is, Args&... args){
    using expander = int[];
    (void)expander{0, (loader<T>::load(is, args), void(), 0)... };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to go all the way to an ADL solution.

First, here is `friend` based load support.

```
struct Thing {
  int a, b;
  friend void load (std::istream& is, Thing& t) {is >> std::skipws >> t.a >> t.b;}
};
```

member based load:

```
struct Object {
  int a, b, c;
  void load (std::istream& is) {is >> std::skipws >> a >> b >> c;}
};
```

First, some metaprogramming boilerplate.  You can do this in fewer lines without the boilerplate, but it makes it cleaner:

```
namespace meta {
  namespace details {
    template<template<class...>class Z, class=void, class...Ts>
    struct can_apply : std::false_type {};
    template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
    struct can_apply<Z, decltype((void)(std::declval<Z<Ts...>>())), Ts...>:
      std::true_type
    {};
  }
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z,void,Ts...>;
}
template<class T>
using member_load = decltype( std::declval<T>().load(std::declval<std::istream&>()) );

template<class T>
using stream_load = decltype( std::declval<std::istream&>() >> std::declval<T>() );
```

which leads to this punchline:

```
template<class T>
using has_member_load = meta::can_apply< member_load, T >;
template<class T>
using has_stream_load = meta::can_apply< stream_load, T >;
```

Now we create a `loading` namespace:

```
namespace loading {
  void load(std::istream&is, std::string& s) {
    while (std::getline (is, s) && s.empty());
  }
  template<class T>
  std::enable_if_t<has_member_load<T&>::value>
  load(std::istream&is, T& t) {
    t.load(is);
  }
  // uses ... to keep lowest priority:
  template<class T>
  std::enable_if_t<has_stream_load<T&>::value>
  load(std::istream& is, T& t, ...) {
    is >> t;
  }

  template<class...Ts>
  void load_many(std::istream&is, Ts&...ts) {
    using discard=int[];
    (void)discard{0,((
      load(is, ts)
    ),void(),0)...};
  }
}
```

we can now call `loading::load_many(is, a, b, c, d)`.

`std::string` has a custom `loading::load` function, as can any other specific types in `std` you want to support.  For example, you can write `template<class T, class A> void load(std::istream& is, std::vector<T,A>&)` in `namespace loading`, and it will just work.

Any class X with a free function `load(istream&, X&)` defined in its namespace will have that function called.

Failing that, any class with a `.load(istream&)` method will have that method called.

Any class X with a `istream& >> X&` overload will get that called if everything above fails.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c539cec06aaebad8).